# How can I enumerate an infinite sequence of integers in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, loops, enumerate

Is there a function in C# that returns an `IEnumerator` of the infinite sequence of integers `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...]`?

I'm currently doing

```
Enumerable.Range (0, 1000000000).Select (x => x * x).TakeWhile (x => (x <= limit))
```

to enumerate all squares up to `limit`. I realize that this is effective, but if there's a built-in function that just counts up from `0`, I would prefer to use it.

Comment: Why would that enumerator ever terminate? But if you think you need it, you can write it yourself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Comment: "infinite" is quite big... do you have a particular data type in mind?

Comment: @JohnSaunders i meant to have jeremy.

Comment: curious to know why you removed the accept flag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This occurred to me, and is suitable for what I was doing:

```
Enumerable.Range (0, int.MaxValue)
```

Comment: You could do unsigned to get more.

Comment: That's a little less than infinity.

Comment: This is far from infinite ... infinitely far in fact! See Daniel whites answer.

Comment: It's infinite as far as `int` and actual use are concerned.

Comment: Note: This won't work if start is larger than zero as start + count needs to be smaller than int.MaxValue.

Comment: If you’re just looking for an unbound version of `Enumerable.Range()`, this is the right way to do it. There’s a reason that `Range()` doesn’t have an unbound version: the maximum that `Int32` goes to is `int.MaxValue`. If you *actually* want to have an unbound thing you should see the other answer and you can’t use `int` at all. I thus think that the question is vague enough that both answers are “right”.

Answer (score 14):

You could roll your own.

```
   IEnumerable<BigInteger> Infinite() {
      BigInteger value = 0;
      while (true) {
        yield return value++;
      }
   }
```

*Edit*

<strike>Why dont you just pass limit in to `Range`? This might be off by one...</strike>

```
Enumerable.Range(0, limit).Select(x => x * x);
```

I was wrong about this edit.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by commenters and illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303045/5134722), the `int` type has max and min bounds, so you can't actually use it as the value type of an infinite sequence. However, you can compromise as follows:

1. Sacrifice the `int` type for something like `BigInteger` - as is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7303045/5134722).
2. Sacrifice "infinity" so that you can keep the `int` type.

Since the former has been covered, I'll cover the latter. Below is a class I used to provide enumeration over `int` values, which will throw an exception if that enumeration gets out of range, either too high or too low. I've unit tested the upper/lower edge cases and it all seems to work fine.

```
internal class SequentialIntProviderImpl : ISequentialIntProvider
    {
        public int Start { get; }
        public int Step { get; }

        private int _current;

        public SequentialIntProviderImpl(int start, int step)
        {
            Start = start;
            Step = step;
            _current = start;
        }

        public int Next()
        {
            AssertNextIsInBounds();
            _current += Step;
            return _current;
        }

        private void AssertNextIsInBounds()
        {
            AssertNextLeqIntMax();
            AssertNextGeqIntMin();
        }

        private void AssertNextGeqIntMin()
        {
            if (Step < 0)
            {
                int MinAllowableCurrent = int.MinValue - Step;
                if (_current < MinAllowableCurrent)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Current index {_current} plus step {Step} will exceed int Min value");
                }
            }
        }

        private void AssertNextLeqIntMax()
        {
            if(Step > 0)
            {
                int maxAllowableCurrent = int.MaxValue - Step;
                if(_current > maxAllowableCurrent)
                {
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Current index {_current} plus step {Step} will exceed int Max value");
                }
            }
        }
    }

/// <summary>
/// Provides iteration over an arithmetic sequence of ints, starting at the given value & increasing by the given step
/// </summary>
public interface ISequentialIntProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Value to start at
    /// </summary>
    int Start { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Value by which to increase the sequence at each successive term
    /// </summary>
    int Step { get; }
    
    /// <returns>The next successive term in the sequence</returns>
    int Next();
}
```